# Unable to retrieve json data using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

i am  a newbie and am stuck at retrieving json data.

following is my index.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min_2.js"> 
$("document").ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("data.php",function(jsondata){
    $("#content").html(jsondata[0].content);    

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<div class="lg"></div>
</body>
```

in my data.php i am using the standard way of encoding and sending the data:

```
// execute query 
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 
         $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
         $jsonserver[$i] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($jsonserver); 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    mysql_free_result($result); 
    // close connection 
    mysql_close($con);
```

i am using mysql database.
when i open localhost/data.php the json data is shown on the browser.
but in case if i open localhost/index.php i donot get any desired output.
Please explain.
Thanks!

Comment: What does `json_encode($jsondata)` output?

Comment: Is that the full code of `index.php`? Do you have an element with `id="content"`?

Comment: **Uncaught ReferenceError: manifest is not defined** this is the error i get in chrome _on pressing ctrl+shift+i_ when i execute data.php, however firebug doesnot show anything of this sort in firefox.

Comment: You should send the response headers **before** the content. Also make sure PHP file doesn't have any characters or spaces before the `<?php` opening tag, because this will cause PHP to send the default headers most common would be: `Content-type: text/html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey,
    u didn't close **script** tag properly

try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min_2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("data.php",function(jsondata){
        $("#content").html(jsondata[0].content);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: also use `console.log(jsondata)` to debug

Comment: great observation, still what i feel the problem lies in data.php as well. chrome inspector gives the follwoing error:Uncaught ReferenceError: manifest is not defined

Answer (score 1):

you need to put all headers before any 'echo's on the page

so:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($jsonserver);
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, doesnt your suggestion doesn't seem to work.